# Creating a scheduler

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a schedule of operations to perform, but the operations can only be performed by certain objects. I'm really struggling with an efficient algorithm and everything I write doesn't seem "neat" and involves multi-dimensional arrays which I'm fine with, but I can't help but feel like there's a better way to do this. (Any help is appreciated)

Let's say for example I create an array of people capable of completing the operations, but let's say a person named "Sally" can only complete certain operations and "Kevin" can only complete a different set of operations... I want to exhaust the operations array completely and not repeat a test with anyone who is capable to perform an operation.

I've created an array of people, I've created an array operations. I've made flags that occur when certain operations are paired with certain people who can't perform the operation.

It becomes a hot-mess real quick and while I can get something "works" I know there has to be a better way to do this and I'd like a "future-proof" way of doing this in case the operations list increases or someone new comes along that is able to perform more or less operations.

Comment: Please edit your question and add code, simple input and desired output and what problem do you have with it, so we can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar situation. Below is something that you could do:

```
>>> people_map = { "Kevin" : ["operation1", "operation3"], "Sally" : ["operation1", "operation4"], "Aaron" : [] }

>>> operations = ["operation1", "operation2", "operation3", "operation4", "operation5"]

>>> initial_set = set(operations)

>>> for person in people:
        person_operations = people_map[person]
        for person_operation in person_operations:
            print("%s can perform %s, so removing it" % (person, person_operation))
            initial_set.discard(person_operation)
            #
            # Assign some operation to someone from initial_set
            #  It would have operations that are al-ready not performed 
            #   by anyone else
            #


Kevin can perform operation1, so removing it
Kevin can perform operation3, so removing it
Sally can perform operation1, so removing it
Sally can perform operation4, so removing it
>>> initial_set

{'operation5', 'operation2'}
>>>
```

In general, you could use [sets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sets.htm) in python. You can also find out union and intersection of sets